# Filehelpers field with multiple numbers

Tags: .net, filehelpers

I wrote a Filehelpers class to read a csv file that contains several fields. In one of these fields, I found that some records have an int, some are blank and some have multiple int separated by a space. When I read the file, an exception is thrown:
Error. Details: FileHelpers.ConvertException: Error Converting '1960 7423 7439 7578' to type: 'Int32'.

I was wondering how to handle this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can read it as string and later split the numbers in your code, or you can create a custom converter.

More info here: http://www.filehelpers.net/example/Converters/CustomConverter/

Comment: I cannot vote up the answer, but this is the right one. Thanks!